# Android View rendering errors on screen reorientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm getting this weird behaviour on a very basic app, where the views render wrongly after a screen reorientation.

The code in the app works as expected when the screen reorients (with activity destruction/creation, since it's not intercepting those events) except for the view display.

When the screen reorients, the view works normally, only with an overlayed ghost image of whatever it looked like when the screen reoriented. It looks like a "burned in" CRT ghost image.

Launching the app in any orientation works normally, the issue only occurs when the screen is reoriented while it is running.

The views are used in a Fragment, which is the only one in its Activity. It happens the same for ListView, DatePicker, and TextView.

The issue occurs in multiple devices:
- nexus 4 running 4.4.3 stock android
- samsung galaxy s running cyanogenmod 10.2.1 (android 4.3.1)
- "galaxy nexus" AVD with API level 18 (android 4.3)

Any idea what is going on here? What more information would be useful for troubleshooting this?

Screenshots below:

[image: landscape, multiple Views in layout]

[image: portrait, ListView]

layout file for the ListView example below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_expenses"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Row for Buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_expenses_button_add"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/label_button_listexpenses_add" />

     </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/label_listexpenses_noexpenses"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that, due to the following code in the Activity classes, the fragment was being repeatedly added to the layout, which resulted in overlapping views (not rendering errors, after all):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_expenses);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_expenses) == null) {
        fragment = ListExpensesFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    } else {
        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_expenses);
    }
}
```

**Solution:** replaced the call to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add()` by `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace()`.